# i am trying to save data from my flutter app to google sheets ,but i get a format exception

Tags: android, api, flutter, google-chrome, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x6LL.png)
i am trying to save data from my flutter app to google sheets ,but i get a format exception:Unexpected character (at character 1) <link rel="shortcut icon" href ="//ssl.gstatic.co....^

booking.dart

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './controller.dart';
import 'models/form.dart';

class Booking extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BookingState createState() => _BookingState();
}

class _BookingState extends State<Booking> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  // TextField Controllers
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController mobileNoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController feedbackController = TextEditingController();

  void _submitForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      FeedbackForm feedbackForm = FeedbackForm(
          nameController.text,
          emailController.text,
          mobileNoController.text,
          feedbackController.text);

      FormController formController = FormController((String response) {
        // print("Response: $response");
        if (response == FormController.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
          //
          _showSnackbar("Feedback Submitted");
        } else {
          _showSnackbar("Error Occurred!");
        }
      });

      _showSnackbar("Submitting Feedback");

      // Submit 'feedbackForm' and save it in Google Sheet

      formController.submitForm(feedbackForm);
    }
  }

  // Method to show snackbar with 'message'.
  _showSnackbar(String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Booking'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 24),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Enter Valid Name";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Enter Valid Email";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: mobileNoController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Enter Valid Phone Number";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Phone Number"),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: feedbackController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Enter Valid Feedback";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Feedback"),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: _submitForm,
                      child: Text('Submit Feedback'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogtor.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rk84.png)

The app does show the submitting feedback part but doesnt reach 'Submitted' part it throws the error mentioned at the top

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't save your script in the google sheet correctly, make sure that you save the script first and then deploy it hence u will get the link, you can replace the link with the new one, and try to run your app again, hope this works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).